# Posting data to Sentiment140 for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

My aim is to perform at least 3 different types of sentiment analysis on data collected from twitter.

I'm attempting to perform sentiment analysis on tweets I've gathered using Python and Twitter API and stored in a database (MySQL & PhpMyAdmin). There are 3 problems I'm having:

1. There aren't many API's that perform sentiment analysis (any suggestions would be helpful)
2. I'm attempting to connect to the Sentiment140 API but my code is returning the following error

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

3. Is there a general way to connect the Sentiment140 API (or any other sentiment analysis API) with my MySQL database for analysis of the text column in the database?

**Python**

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson'
values = {'data': [{'text': 'I love Titanic.'}, {'text': 'I hate Titanic.'}]} 

data = json.dumps(values) # instead of urllib.urlencode(values)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)
page = response.read()
```

All help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please tell me the version of `python` you are using. 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [urllib docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples), you have to convert your strs to bytes before feeding it to urlopen:

> Note that params output from urlencode is encoded to bytes before it is sent to urlopen as data.

You can do so by calling `.encode()` on `data`:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson'
values = {'data': [{'text': 'I love Titanic.'}, {'text': 'I hate Titanic.'}]} 

data = json.dumps(values)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=data.encode("utf-8"))
page = response.read()
```